# Change switch color programmatically in Android Studio using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to add a color to the switches in Android Studio using Kotlin
I tried few answers fronm this forum and couldn't get it to work

Is it possible to make this work programmatically?

[Switch color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om7fR.png)

I modified my code as mentioned in answer  @vishnu

Full code is below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "ResourceType", "UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialCode")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        switchButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener{_, isChecked ->
            if(isChecked) {
                switchButton1.text = "Switch 1 ON"
                switchButton1.thumbDrawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.switch_track_checked_true_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
                Toast.makeText(this, "First Switch Button: ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else {
                switchButton1.text = "Switch 1 OFF"
                switchButton1.thumbDrawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.switch_track_checked_false_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
                Toast.makeText(this, "First Switch Button: OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
        switchButton2.setOnCheckedChangeListener{_, isChecked ->
            if(isChecked) {
                switchButton2.text = "Switch 2 ON"
                Toast.makeText(this, "Second Switch Button: ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else {
                switchButton2.text = "Switch 2 OFF"
                Toast.makeText(this, "Second Switch Button: OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
        buttonResetSwitch.setOnClickListener{
            switchButton1.isChecked = false
            switchButton2.isChecked = false
        }
    }
}
```

I am not seeing the color while loading the app.
This color change happens only after activating the switch.
How can I get the color change while loading the app (as shown in "Switch OFF" position)

[Switch Color Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPaOl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a material switch

```
mySwitch.setTrackTintList("your_color")
mySwitch.setThumbTintList("your_color")
```

or like this

```
if (isChecked) {
   mySwitch.getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.switch_track_checked_true_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
} else {
   mySwitch.getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.switch_track_checked_false_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```

Comment: I got the code working... but the color doesn't work once it's loaded. please see my original post

Comment: just call this method while loading ie on onCreate()

Comment: I tried to modify the code and getting error, I am not sure how to get this working. I posted the full code for your reference.

Comment: add this code after setContentView switchButton1.isChecked = false
            switchButton2.isChecked = false

Comment: still the same. unable to get the color while loading...

Comment: sorry put that after setOnCheckedChangeListener

Answer (score 3):

You can use this condition for kotlin. You should try this.

```
// condiotion while switch is on 
if(mySwitch.isChecked){
    mySwitch.setThumbResource(getColor(R.color.yourcolor))
    mySwitch.setTrackResource(getColor(R.color.yourcolor))
} 
// Condition while switch is off
else {
    mySwitch.setThumbResource(getColor(R.color.yourcolor))
    mySwitch.setTrackResource(getColor(R.color.yourcolor))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The switch color follows the `textColor` attribute. You can use [setSwitchTextAppearance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch#setSwitchTextAppearance(android.content.Context,%20int)) to change the `textColor`.

From the same `Switch` docs,
`the textAppearance and the related setTypeface() methods control the typeface and style of label text, whereas the switchTextAppearance and the related setSwitchTypeface() methods control that of the thumb.`